# AVAudioEngine recording microphone input seems to stop upon playing music

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioengine, shazam

I’m recording microphone input to match it to a song in the Shazam catalog. This works, but if I `start()` the `AVAudioEngine` then something happens like music starts playing via `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer.play()`, it seems the audio engine stops or gets interrupted. The microphone recording shuts off, thus the `SHSessionDelegate` never finds a match or fails with an error, so my UI is stuck showing it's listening when it’s not anymore. Is there a way to be informed when this happens so that I may update the UI to handle cancelation?

```
private lazy var shazamAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
private lazy var shazamSession: SHSession = {
    let session = SHSession()
    session.delegate = self
    return session
}()

...

try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.record)

//Create an audio format for our buffers based on the format of the input, with a single channel (mono)
let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: shazamAudioEngine.inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate, channels: 1)

//Install a "tap" in the audio engine's input so that we can send buffers from the microphone to the session
shazamAudioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 2048, format: audioFormat) { [weak self] buffer, when in
    //Whenever a new buffer comes in, we send it over to the session for recognition
    self?.shazamSession.matchStreamingBuffer(buffer, at: when)
}

do {
    try shazamAudioEngine.start()
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing `isRunning` tracks this state, so it changes from `true` to `false` when you start playing music and the microphone stops being recorded. Unfortunately that property can't be observed with KVO so what I did was set up a repeating `Timer` to detect if it changes to handle cancelation, making sure to `invalidate()` the timer when other state changes occur.

```
audioEngineRunningTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in    
    //the audio engine stops running when you start playing music for example, so handle cancelation here
    if self?.shazamAudioEngine.isRunning == false {
        //...
    }
}
```